# How do I change directory and copy a file using FTP?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, ftp

This code logs in, and tries to change the directory, and then list the files in the directory:

```
Net::FTP.open(DOMAIN_NAME, LOGIN, PASSWORD) do |ftp|
  files = ftp.chdir("forms/")      
  puts files.list
end
```

I get this error when I run it:

```
undefined method `list' for nil:NilClass
```

The folder definitely exists. I saw it when I tried connecting using cyberduck, and if I do `ftp.list`.

What am I doing wrong?

Also how would I download a CSV file from the FTP server and then open it?

I tried reading the docs on rubylang and am quite stuck. If anyone could help that would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`chdir` changes the directory. If you look at the underlying source, it doesn't return anything.

`list` returns the list of files:

> Returns an array of file information in the directory (the output is like `ls -l`). If a block is given, it iterates through the listing.

As a result `files` will be nil, because `chdir` didn't return anything. Instead you need to do something like:

```
ftp.chdir('forms/')
files = ftp.list
```

Look at [Example #2 in the docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/net/ftp/rdoc/Net/FTP.html#class-Net%3a%3aFTP-label-Example+2) for an example, and ignore that they try to assign the result of `chdir`.

[`nlist`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/net/ftp/rdoc/Net/FTP.html#method-i-nlst) would be even better than `list` if all you want is the list of names. Use `list` if you want a long-listing of the files so you can parse out permissions, sizes, etc.

Comment: I notice he asked how to copy a file, I don't see an answer to that here?

Comment: The OP asked two questions that aren't really tied together. The problem was solved. The second question is clearly covered in the FTP and IO docs. You're welcome to answer that with code if you choose.